# Go to last row from result set in jdbc with sql server

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, resultset

i try to select from my table, only select the last row. I've tried this :

```
rset = s.executeQuery("select noorder from orders");
rset.last();
String noorder = rset.getString("noorder");`
```

rset is resultset, and s is statement. But it throw an exception : ResultSet may only be accessed in a forward direction`

I've tried this to :

```
if (rset != null) {                
   while(rset.next()){
       rset.last();
   }
}
```

Am I doing wrong? Any idea? Thanks

Edit :
This is the answer, as suggested by @Bhavik-Ambani (thanks for him). And this is my code :

```
        Statement s2 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rset = s2.executeQuery("select noorder from orders");
        rset.afterLast();
        GETLASTINSERTED:
        while(rset.previous()){
            noorder = rset.getString("noorder");
            break GETLASTINSERTED;//to read only the last row
        }
```

Hope it will be help another. Java rocks!

Comment: If you know you want the last one, why don't you just sort the query in reverse order? Also: without an explicit `ORDER BY` first and last don't have real meaning (as the order is undefined).

Comment: @Markrotteveel that will work to, but my method works too, so I think nothing wrong with it, am i right? or my method has weakness?

Comment: depending on the database and the JDBC driver your method could result in a lot more processing on the DB (eg: reading all rows) and a lot more data being sent between the DB and the JDBC driver (eg: sending all rows).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A default ResultSet object is not updatable and has a cursor that moves forward only. Thus, you can iterate through it only once and only from the first row to the last row.

At code level you can do the following thing

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select noorder from orders");
resultSet.afterLast();
while (resultSet.previous()) {
  String productCode = resultSet.getString("col_one");
  String productName = resultSet.getString("col_two");

}
connection.close();
```

Comment: in the while() loop, is that only take a row, or takes all the row backward?

Comment: It will take records from the last record and to the backward. If you dont want to iterate backward you can just place if condition and get the last record value.

Answer (score 2):

The `isLast()` should be what you're looking for.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

while(rs.next()) {
  if(rs.isLast()) {
      // is last row in ResultSet
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember to apply an `order by` clause otherwise the last entry in your `ResultSet` may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
`connection.prepareStatement(sql,  ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);`

Answer (score 0):

```
rset = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY unique_column DESC LIMIT 1");

String noorder = rset.getString("noorder");`
```

Comment: my unique_column is a String with set of data, for example '12-05-0001/E , 12 represents year, 05 represents Month and 0001 represent number. I dont think your method can work as it try to order the column. I think my column won't ordered correctly. But thanks for your help. It'll work only if the column orderable, like usual string or integer..