# How to select the last row of database in jsp?

Tags: java, database

I am not able to display the last row of my database in jsp. I already tried to print `rs.getString(1)`, but it does not work.

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select MAX(CustomerID) from Customer");  
while(rs.next()){out.print(rs.getString(1));}
```

Comment: What database are you using? What you mean with last: last id? last updated item?

Comment: How does it not work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: There is no such thing as the "last row" in a relational database.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659083/go-to-last-row-from-result-set-in-jdbc-with-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you want but if you are trying to get the whole row there are some ways to accomplish that

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select max(customerid) as id from customer");
rs.next();
String id = rs.getString("id");
rs = st.executeQuery("select field_a, field_b from customer where customerid = " + id);
rs.next();
String row = id + "," + rs.getString("field_a") + "," + rs.getString("field_b");
out.println(row);
```

Of course you need to replace the `field_a` and `field_b` columns with the ones in your `customer` table and add or remove columns according to your needs.

The shorter way is using `order by` and `limit` keywords like this

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select customerid, field_a, field_b from customer order by customerid desc limit 1");
rs.next();
String row = rs.getString("customerid") + "," + rs.getString("field_a") + "," + rs.getString("field_b");
out.println(row);
```

Be secure of add a `primary key` or `unique` constraint to the `customerid` column for improve the performance of the both methods.