# Delete last row java MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I have button deleting line from database. I want to ask how to delete last row in java? i just know method from `resultset` is `.getLong(1)` but it's for current row aka top row.how to get last row in java resultset?

this is my code

```
try{
    koneksi_db();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from line");
    rs.next();
    long id = rs.getLong(1);
    stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM line WHERE UniqueID = '"+id+"'");
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error menghapus line");    
}
```

Comment: "Last" does not have any meaning when there is no sort involved.

Comment: im sorry i don't understand what's your comment?

Comment: Mandatory comment: switch to using [`PreparedStatements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of appending variables into the query literal.

Comment: @FRIDY, what Tunaki means is that the ordering of rows in the result set of `select * from line` is undefined. Deleting the "last row" (or the first for that matter) doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You can have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10659132/4890123

. I think it suits your needs.

Comment: Bad idea to mingle Swing and database code together this way.  Proper layering would suggest that you should not have Swing in your database layer.

Comment: I'm guessing you are new to JDBC. You only get the top row because you only looked at the first result with rs.next()- you need to loop through the full result set using a loop- while(rs.hasNext())- when you exit the loop the id will have the last records id copied to it. Finding the last id this way and sending a delete stament after is a very poor technique- you do not actually need to use any java variables at all unless you are using the values in your java program. See my answer for how to do it using a single sql statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define 'last'- you can do it by ordering your results just add "order by [column]" to the end of your query and either "ASC" or "DESC" for ascending or descending order. You can sort by any column in either order which is why it is important you define what the 'last' record is first
Then add a limit so only the first row is returned: "Limit 1" (switch your ordering so this 1 row is the same as your defined 'last'. You can then use an "IN" statement to match your statement with a subquery as part of your where clause in your delete statement. This assumes there are no duplicates and deletes one record. Or alternatively you could use the max/min value of the column- this will delete all records with the min/max value if there are duplicate records with the same min/max value for the column you are sorting by.

The first technique- the "WHERE IN" compares the column to all the results in the subquery- which is why we limit the results of the sub query to one result:

DELETE FROM [table] where [column] in (SELECT [column] from [table] order by [column] asc limit 1)

The second technique is to do the same using a min or max function in your IN clause- which one you use depends on how you define the "last" record- if you are absolutely sure there are no duplicates this is slightly more efficient.

DELETE FROM [table] where [column] in (SELECT max([column]) from [table])

You may have to double check my SQL to make sure it is compatible with mySQL, some databases use "IS IN" but this is the basic idea.